# How can I install phalcon on Ubunutu?

Tags: php

I am installing the Phalcon framework on Ubuntu. I used Apache as a web-server. I installed `phalcon` and `psr`. I can find shows that `phalcon` and `psr` in the output `phpinfo()`:

[image: phpinfo() output]

When using `composer install`, I get these errors:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-psr ^0.7 has the wrong version (1.0.0) installed. Install or enable PHP's psr extension.
  Problem 2
    - phalcon/devtools v4.0.3 requires vlucas/phpdotenv ^3.6 -> satisfiable by vlucas/phpdotenv[3.6.x-dev, v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4, v3.6.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phalcon/devtools v4.0.2 requires vlucas/phpdotenv ^3.6 -> satisfiable by vlucas/phpdotenv[3.6.x-dev, v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4, v3.6.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phalcon/devtools v4.0.1 requires vlucas/phpdotenv ^3.6 -> satisfiable by vlucas/phpdotenv[3.6.x-dev, v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4, v3.6.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phalcon/devtools v4.0.0 requires vlucas/phpdotenv ^3.6 -> satisfiable by vlucas/phpdotenv[3.6.x-dev, v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4, v3.6.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for phalcon/devtools ~4.0 -> satisfiable by phalcon/devtools[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3].
```

What is the reason? Do I need to add any other command?

Answer (score 0):

## Problem 1

I think you installed natively `php-psr` from Ubuntu package while your composer requests version 0.7. You might try to uninstall Ubuntu package first with `apt remove php-psr`.

## Problem 2

Try again when problem 1 is fixed, it might be a dependency issue due to first problem.